# Kotlin class property not changing

Tags: kotlin

I am wanting to have a kotlin class that manages the current target for some exercises. There are two main functions for this, `updateTarget()`, which goes to the next target in the list, and `currentTarget()`, which simply returns the current target.

However, the target is never actually changing. `x` is always 0.

I have two questions regarding this. Firstly, why is the property not changing? Secondly, is there another design pattern I am missing which would be better suited towards my goal?

```
class Targets(private val targets: ArrayList<Target>)
{
    init {
        require(targets.size > 1) {"There must be more than one target in targets"}
    }

    // Keeps track of current index of target. Has a range of 0 to targets.size-1
    private var x = 0

    /**
     * Returns the current exercise target
     */
    fun currentTarget() : Target {
        return targets[x]
    }

    /**
     * Updates the current exercise target to the next target in the list
     *
     * Returns true if a repetition has been made.
     */
    fun updateTarget() : Boolean {
        x += 1
        x %= targets.size
        return x == 0
    }
}
```

Caller of the code:

```
if (target.isMetBy(value)) {
    val repetitionMade = currentExercise.targets.updateTarget()
    target = currentExercise.targets.currentTarget()
    if (repetitionMade) {
        numberRepetitions += 1
    }
}
```

Effectively the target is never changing, even when the value meets the target.

Answer (score 0):

For me your code works fine. (Kotlin 1.3.50 on Java 11 AdoptOpenJDK)

run it like that:

```
class TargetApp {}
fun main() {
    val targets = Targets(arrayListOf(Target("one"), Target("two"), Target("three")))

    var numberRepetitions = 0;
    for(i in 1..10){
        val current = targets.currentTarget()
        val repetitionMade = targets.updateTarget()
        if(repetitionMade){
            numberRepetitions += 1
        }
        println("Index $i with current target '${current.name}' and $numberRepetitions repetitions")
    }
}
```

with Target

```
data class Target(
    val name: String
)
```

and "Targets"

```
class Targets(private val targets: ArrayList<Target>) {
    init {
        require(targets.size > 1) { "There must be more than one target in targets" }
    }

    private var x = 0

    fun currentTarget(): Target {
        return targets[x]
    }

    fun updateTarget(): Boolean {
        x += 1
        x %= targets.size
        return x == 0
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Index 1 with current target 'one' and 0 repetitions
Index 2 with current target 'two' and 0 repetitions
Index 3 with current target 'three' and 1 repetitions
Index 4 with current target 'one' and 1 repetitions
Index 5 with current target 'two' and 1 repetitions
Index 6 with current target 'three' and 2 repetitions
Index 7 with current target 'one' and 2 repetitions
Index 8 with current target 'two' and 2 repetitions
Index 9 with current target 'three' and 3 repetitions
Index 10 with current target 'one' and 3 repetitions
```

I guess your problem is located somewhere else.

(I swapped the call of currentTarget and updateTarget, cause otherwise your first "current" Target will be from index 1 so index 0 is skipped.)

Comment: I just found my issue! Thank you heaps! I made a dumb mistake. The targets class was a member of another class, and set as a val, not var. Silly me.